# International Components for Unicode (ICU) Date Formatter for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date-format, unicode, localization, international-components-unicode

Regarding to [ICU - International Components for Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org/) definition:

> ICU is a mature, widely used set of C/C++ and Java libraries providing Unicode and Globalization support for software applications. ICU is widely portable and gives applications the same results on all platforms and between C/C++ and Java software.

one of important part is formatting:

> Formatting: Format numbers, dates, times and currency amounts according the conventions of a chosen locale. This includes translating month and day names into the selected language, choosing appropriate abbreviations, ordering fields correctly, etc. This data also comes from the Common Locale Data Repository.

which implemented in vary languages; I would like to know if there is any implementation or work for MySQL to add this feature for Unicode date formatting?

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43425047/international-components-for-unicode-icu-date-formatter-for-mysql

Comment: @RickJames You are right but no one answer it there and I thought here is right place to ask again

Comment: Perhaps this suffices?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format

Comment: @RickJames thanks for your help. It was good to know this but its not solving my problem.
I'm interesting on **[Calendar](http://userguide.icu-project.org/datetime/calendar)** section.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the answer is...  Use MySQL to store dates/datetimes/timestamps in the limited formats that it provides, then use app code -- possibly some library in your app language -- to get at fancier formatting.

As a general rule, a database is responsible for storing; the application is responsible for formatting.

See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html

Comment: Good Answer. For example, the *java.time* classes use the cultural norms rules provided by the *Unicode CLDR* for automatic localization when generating strings representing date-time values. This is default behavior in Java 9 and later (at least on Oracle JDK & OpenJDK), optional in earlier Java.

Comment: @BasilBourque - Java may be the best approach.  Meanwhile, I added a link to MySQL's meager Locale support.  (It goes back at least to version 5.5.)